# ClamAV scan results /home/user [failed]

Tags: clamav

DirectAdmin ClamAV error one user not scann all the time failed and this error

```
LibClamAV Warning: PNG: Unexpected early end-of-file.
LibClamAV Warning: PNG: Unexpected early end-of-file.
LibClamAV Warning: PNG: Unexpected early end-of-file.
LibClamAV Warning: PNG: Unexpected early end-of-file.
LibClamAV Warning: PNG: Unexpected early end-of-file.
LibClamAV Warning: PNG: Unexpected early end-of-file.
LibClamAV Warning: PNG: Unexpected early end-of-file.
LibClamAV Warning: PNG: Unexpected early end-of-file.
LibClamAV Warning: PNG: Unexpected early end-of-file.
LibClamAV Warning: PNG: Unexpected early end-of-file.
LibClamAV Warning: PNG: Unexpected early end-of-file.
LibClamAV Warning: PNG: Unexpected early end-of-file.
LibClamAV Warning: PNG: Unexpected early end-of-file.
LibClamAV Warning: PNG: Unexpected early end-of-file.
LibClamAV Warning: PNG: Unexpected early end-of-file.
LibClamAV Warning: PNG: Unexpected early end-of-file.
LibClamAV Warning: PNG: Unexpected early end-of-file.
LibClamAV Warning: PNG: Unexpected early end-of-file.
LibClamAV Warning: PNG: Unexpected early end-of-file.
LibClamAV Warning: PNG: Unexpected early end-of-file.
LibClamAV Warning: PNG: Unexpected early end-of-file.
LibClamAV Warning: PNG: Unexpected early end-of-file.
LibClamAV Warning: PNG: Unexpected early end-of-file.
LibClamAV Warning: PNG: Unexpected early end-of-file.
LibClamAV Warning: PNG: Unexpected early end-of-file.
LibClamAV Warning: PNG: Unexpected early end-of-file.
LibClamAV Warning: PNG: Unexpected early end-of-file.
----------- SCAN SUMMARY -----------
Known viruses: 8665207
Engine version: 0.103.7
Scanned directories: 24465
Scanned files: 810008
Infected files: 0
Total errors: 1
Data scanned: 111495.12 MB
Data read: 276246.50 MB (ratio 0.40:1)
Time: 22143.540 sec (369 m 3 s)
Start Date: 2023:01:19 08:15:44
End Date:   2023:01:19 14:24:47

exit status 2**strong text**
```

Any help ? how to scan that user ?

Comment: Warnings are not errors. Most likely clamav is fauity: it uses checks that are made and work for windows and not for linux. clamav is only good for scanning windows files.

Comment: The very first hit on Google for "PNG: Unexpected early end-of-file" explains it. "That just means that the PNG file is either not a PNG for or is corrupted
- perhaps truncated."